# Render partial in rails passing values together + AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've been stuck in this for 2 hours already. I'm using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.1.1.

I have this set of radio buttons:

**new.html.erb:**

```
<% PokemonDefault.where(forme: nil).each do |pkm| %>
     <li>
          <%= f.radio_button :number, pkm.num, :onclick => 'render_picture();' %>
          <%= image_tag 'miniaturePokemon/'+pkm.code+'.png' %>
          <span class="name"><%= pkm.name %></span>
     </li>
<% end %>
```

I have also this js:

**new.js.erb** (note: the "????" is one of the fields I don't know how to fill)

```
function render_picture() {
$('#pokemon_picture').html('<%=j render :partial => 'picture',:locals => {:number => ???? } %>');
```

}

And finaly, the picture template:

**_picture.html.erb**

```
<%= number %>
```

All I want is that when I click in one of the radio buttons, I get '_picture' rendered inside '#pokemon_picture', containing the *pkm.num* attibute. ( I want to use this number to render a picture, each picture has it own number.)

Just to clarify: each *pkm* has its own *number*, and I want it rendered as soon as I click in the Radio Button, through Ajax.

Comment: First thing is the render_picture function will be loaded only once on one page load so if you want dynamic values based on radio button check box as I see your showing a number. You can pass 'number' to onclick render_picture function and replace it directly  no need to do render partial

Comment: Actually, I don't want to show the number. I want to render a picture based on that number.

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
<%= f.radio_button :number,
                   pkm.num,
                  :onclick => 'render_picture(this);',
                  :data-num => pkm.num 
%>

function render_picture(tag) {
  var num = $(tag).data('num');
  $('#pokemon_picture').html('<%=j render :partial => 'picture',:locals => {:number => ' + num + ' } %>');
}
```

**Or**

```
<%= f.radio_button :number,
                   pkm.num,
                  :onclick => "render_picture(#{pkm.num});"
%>

function render_picture(num) {
  $('#pokemon_picture').html('<%=j render :partial => 'picture',:locals => {:number => ' + num + ' } %>');
}
```

Comment: Both of them just render "+ num +".